# Transfer categories and products from store to store

Tags: category

I want to transfer a lot of categories and corresponding products from one store to another.
Wat is the best way to do this, the normal Magento export profiles do not include group pricing for example..

Magento version 1.8.1.0

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options here.

1. Build a script that uses the api to call one store and move to the next,
2. Build a script that uses an import tool like [FastSimpleImport](https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport) or another import wrapper, first get you products and then set your products.
3. Build your own script from scratch that deals with collections and sets store etc,
4. A mixture of all of the above,